# How can update roomle component via roomle API?

Tags: roomle

I'm following docs of roomle at https://docs.roomle.com/rapi/endpoints/Component.html#post
but I dont see any example for the body content of  update method.

And I got an error message when update a component

```
{
"error": {
    "type": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "you need to be in cms context",
    "status": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "statusCode": 400
}}
```

My body request -
PUT: https://api.roomle.com/v2/components/component_test

```
{
"component": {
    "externalIdentifier": "component_test",
    "catalog": "delife",
    "id": "delife:component_test",
    "configuration": "{\"id\":\"delife:component_test\",\"parameterGroups\":[{\"key\":\"chairGr\",\"global\":true,\"labels\":{\"en\":\"Sitzschale1\"}}]}",
    "active": false,
    "version": 3
}}
```

P/s: with the api to get component detail work good

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the intended way is to use the Rubens Admin (admin.roomle.com) interface for posting catalog changes. Please refer to https://docs.roomle.com/web/datamanagement/ for documentation on Rubens Admin.